# 2 QMs talking each other via Sender and RCVR not working

Tags: mq

I have 2 QMs...QM1.QM and QM2.QM..below are the commands executed and not able to see communication..Please correct me ...some thing is not correct...MQ version [ 8.0.0.6]..After created both QMs..executed below commands..all below commands executed without any error/exception.

```
runmqsc QM1.QM
define listener(LISTENER) trptype(tcp) control(qmgr) port(1414)
start listener(LISTENER)
define qlocal(Q5)
DEFINE QLOCAL(QM2) TRIGGER INITQ(SYSTEM.CHANNEL.INITQ) PROCESS(P1) USAGE(XMITQ)
define qremote(Q6_QM2) rname(Q6) rqmname(QM2.QM) xmitq(QM2)
define channel(QM2.TO.QM1) chltype(RCVR) trptype(TCP)
define channel(QM1.TO.QM2) chltype(SDR) conname('127.0.0.1(1415)') xmitq(QM2) trptype(TCP)
DEFINE PROCESS(P1) USERDATA(QM1.TO.QM2)
start channel(QM1.TO.QM2)

runmqsc QM2.QM
define listener(LISTENER) trptype(tcp) control(qmgr) port(1415)
start listener(LISTENER)
define qlocal(Q6)
DEFINE QLOCAL(QM1) TRIGGER INITQ(SYSTEM.CHANNEL.INITQ) PROCESS(P2) USAGE(XMITQ)
define qremote(Q5_QM1) rname(Q5) rqmname(QM1.QM) xmitq(QM1)
define channel(QM1.TO.QM2) chltype(RCVR) trptype(TCP)
define channel(QM2.TO.QM1) chltype(SDR) conname('127.0.0.1(1414)') xmitq(QM1) trptype(TCP)
DEFINE PROCESS(P2) USERDATA(QM2.TO.QM1)
start channel(QM2.TO.QM1)

ps -ef | grep runmqlsr
mqm      14789 14773  0 07:17 ?        00:00:00 /opt/mqm/bin/runmqlsr -r -m QM1.QM -t TCP -p 1414
mqm      14804     1  0 07:17 pts/3    00:00:00 runmqlsr -t tcp -m QM1.QM -p 2020
mqm      14919 14902  0 07:17 ?        00:00:00 /opt/mqm/bin/runmqlsr -r -m QM2.QM -t TCP -p 1415
mqm      14935     1  0 07:17 pts/3    00:00:00 runmqlsr -t tcp -m QM2.QM -p 2021
```

**5:33 PM Saturday, September 26, 2020**

```
amqsput Q6_QM2 QM1.QM
Sample AMQSPUT0 start
target queue is QM2
test-from-qm1-one

Sample AMQSPUT0 end

amqsbcg Q6 QM2.QM
00000000:  7465 7374 2D66 726F 6D2D 716D 2D6F 6E65           'test-from-qm-one'


 amqsput Q5_QM1 QM2.QM
Sample AMQSPUT0 start
target queue is Q5_QM2
test-from-qm-two

Sample AMQSPUT0 end


amqsbcg Q5 QM1.QM
00000000:  7465 7374 2D66 726F 6D2D 716D 2D6F 6E65           'test-from-qm-two'
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222163/discussion-on-question-by-mq-beginner-2-qms-talking-each-other-via-sender-and-rc).

Comment: Did you resolve this with setting `INITQ` and **`TRIGDATA`**?

Comment: could edit question or give full command..so that i can execute and try